# Kettle - Parallel readings of files and Multithreading

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, pentaho, kettle

It is possible with Kettle to **read different files simultaneously**? How does it work?
There is the notion of parallelism? Is it related with threads?

Thanks

Comment: I do not think this should be on hold. It's a good question, and there are various answers. It is certainly not "too broad."  To be clear - the notion on being "too broad" is made irrelevant by the fact the user is talking about PDI/Kettle.

Answer (score 2):

This is naturally how Kettle works. Each step in a transform runs in its own thread. So if you have multiple input steps, each reading a different file, each file will be read in its own thread.

Note, this is true of transforms, not jobs. Parallel execution in jobs is trickier. For an example of sequencing parallel jobs, check out my answer here:

[Waiting for Transformations in a Job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675520/waiting-for-transformations-in-a-job/16702589#16702589)